# Exclude rows until a value from a column has changed

Tags: sql, oracle

I needed to select only the rows where in the Payment Term value has changed. My goal is to provide the Payment Term history changes of a certain account. I have a query below that is returning all the transactions for each account.

```
 select hca.account_name "Account Name",
           hca.account_number "Account Number",
           rt.name "Payment Term",
           rt.description "Description",
           trunc (apsa.creation_date) "Creation Date",
    from ra_terms rt,
         hz_cust_accounts hca,
         ar_payment_schedules_all apsa
    where apsa.class = 'INV'
          and apsa.invoice_currency_code = 'USD'
          and apsa.customer_id = hca.cust_account_id (+)
          and apsa.term_id = rt.term_id
          and hca.account_number = 99820
    group by apsa.creation_date,
             rt.name,
             rt.description,
             hca.account_name,
             hca.account_number,
             apsa.trx_number
    order by hca.account_number DESC,
             "Creation Date" ASC
```

Current output:

```
|  Account Name   | Account Number | Payment Term | Creation Date | <br/>

| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 50-0     | 1/16/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 45-0     | 1/17/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 50-0     | 1/31/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 50-0     | 2/22/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 45-0     | 3/21/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 50-0     | 4/27/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 45-0     | 3/14/2019     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 45-0     | 3/14/2019     |<br/>
```

Expected output:

```
|  Account Name   | Account Number | Payment Term | Creation Date |<br/>

| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 50-0     | 1/16/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 45-0     | 1/17/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 50-0     | 1/31/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 45-0     | 3/21/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 50-0     | 4/27/2017     |<br/>
| ABC Corporation |          99820 | PDC 45-0     | 3/14/2019     |<br/>
```

--note that the 4th and last row of the current output table is not reflected in the expected output table since the payment term value did not change.

Comment: just try to use `distinct` before your columns in the `select-list` such as `select distinct hca.account_name "Account Name",...`

Comment: What is your Oracle version? This is very easy to do with the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause in versions 12.1 and higher; a bit harder, with analytic functions (search for "start of group method"), in older versions.

Comment: @mathguy, version is 11.2.

Comment: @Vic Have you tried analytic functions like `lead(...) over (...)`?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, I think I cannot use distinct since Payment Terms can be repeated per costumer as long as it is not equal with its most recent term.

Comment: @fen1x, I think its the same with what Tejash has suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using analytical function `lag`.

```
Select * from
(select t.*, 
        lag(t."Payment Term") 
        over (partition by t."Account Number" order by t."Creation Date") as lag_pay
From (your_query)
)
Where lag_pay is null or lag_pay <> "Payment Term";
```

Cheers!!